# jQuery - Hide DIV which has a span element with certain text inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have several divs with the same class names and varying IDs. The ID is not set for the text I need to target

I need to target the Telephone Call text. If the div contains that text, how do I hide the containing div

```
<div id="rn_FieldDisplay_155" class="rn_FieldDisplay rn_Output">
   <span class="rn_DataLabel">Telephone Call </span>
   <div class="rn_DataValue">No</div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following to no avail

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rn_FieldDisplay > span:contains('Telephone Call')").hide ();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code it's working... take a look. https://jsfiddle.net/2ako5ok7/

Comment: That deletes the span and not the containing div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code is hiding the span, but not the parent div, you can target the div to be hidden using mostly the same code you already wrote.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rn_FieldDisplay > span:contains('Telephone Call')").parent().hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting it's child instead of the element itself :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rn_FieldDisplay *:contains('Telephone Call')").hide ();
});
```

Comment: The OP wants to hide the Parent

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`find()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJ7O3tkqnUAhVFRY8KHV5PCJoQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ffind%2F&usg=AFQjCNG-8t8FlAFURjmRfahbB_JtshKgfg&sig2=M_LN2xTVTvAYb523mcrMrA) function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rn_FieldDisplay").find(":contains('Telephone Call')").hide ();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rn_FieldDisplay_155" class="rn_FieldDisplay rn_Output">
    <span class="rn_DataLabel">Telephone Call </span>
    <div class="rn_DataValue">No</div>
        <p class="rn_DataLabel">Telephone Call </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this:

```
if ($(".rn_FieldDisplay > span:contains('Telephone Call')").length > 0) {
    $(".rn_FieldDisplay > span").hide();
}
```